# how to add bootstrap jquery script in view cakephp 2.5.5?

Tags: cakephp

I am trying add simple bootstrap jquery functionality in cakephp 2.5.5but i dont know how to add script in view.Please suggest me some code?

in webroot jquery folder i have created `custom.js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $("#hide").click(function(){ $("p").hide(); }); });
```

in view i have

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->css('index'); 
echo $this->Html->script('custom');
?>
 <p ><?php echo "some text"; ?></p>
<?php echo $this->Form->button('click me',array('id'=>'hide'));?>
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Check CakePHP documentation http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html

Comment: In Stackoverflow any question is editable, so any required details, you are able to add them to your question not in comment, specially, those have code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say path to custom.js file is in webroot/js/jquery/custom.js, then you can have it in view with

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery/custom.js'); ?>
```

If the path is not in the folder webroot/js (say webroot/jquery/custom.js), then specify the whole path to the file like

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('/jquery/custom.js'); ?>
```

Always add the line below at at the end as described [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html)

```
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
```

Comment: What is it that you actually failed to do? The script execution or adding the script to the page. To see if the script is on page view the source and see if you can see that portion of code in the souce.
Otherwise, look at the selector, give an id to p as follows:
<p id="givenID">Some TExt</p>
In your script in place of ( $("p")) write ( $("#givenID"))

Comment: When i click that button ,it wil not hide paragraph

Comment: Have you downloaded and imported jquery library? If not that's the first thing you need to do before.

Comment: I have added bootstrap jquery library

Comment: do you have
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
as described here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html

Comment: Thank s a lot . finaly working exactly what i need. Your answer helped me a lot. Thank you once again.

Comment: sorry i cant vote that answer because of low reputation